# Why is $(e^{2πi})^i$ different from $(e^i)^{2πi}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, exponentiation, eulers-number-e

I'm a high school senior and this question has been on my mind since 8th grade, since I've learned Euler's formula but I've thought about it a lot more recently. According to Wolfram Alpha:
[(e^i)^(2iπ)=e^(-2π)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGi5d.jpg)

[(e^(2iπ))^(i)=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYLxr.jpg)

How is this possible??????

In other words, if

$$ e^{iπ} = -1 $$

$$ e^{2iπ} = 1 $$

$$ (e^{2iπ})^i = 1^i $$

$$ e^{-2π} = 1 $$

Where is the error in this reasoning?

Comment: Many of the identities you think you know about exponents should have come with a warning that they only are guaranteed to work when using non-negative real bases and real exponents.  $(a^b)^c$ is not necessarily the same as $a^{bc}$

Comment: What is your *definition* of $z^w$ for complex $z$ and $w$? And did you actually check that exponentiation of complex numbers satisfies all the algebraic rules of exponentiation of positive real numbers?

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659145/ei-pi-paradox-invalid-proof-that-4-pi-2-0)

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks so much! Yes, that definitely answered my question and the article was really helpful.